# HP proliant server showing all hard drives as one drive

Tags: hp-proliant

I have a HP proliant server with 6 full HDD slots. When I run this command:

```
fdisk -l
```

It is showing all 6 HDDs as /dev/sda instead of separate sda sdb adc ... disks.
How can I show drives separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HP server very likely has an HP SmartArray configured with a single RAID array. To let the OS see the single HDDs you need to configure the RAID card in *passthrough* mode which, on recent SmartArray, is done by removing any RAID config. Please note that on old SmartArray passthrough is not supported at all so, depending on your HP server generation, you had to live with using the array (rather than using the single disks).

That said, I strongly suggest you to get in touch with a professional IT consultant.

Comment: Does G6 support this passthrough and do you have any reference link?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: So what happens if I remove some hard drives?

Comment: If the array has some redundancy, it will become degraded. If the array has no redundancy (ie: RAID0, RAID5 with one broken disk, etc) it will become FAILED and you will lose any data. Again, if you need to ask such questions, seek a professional IT partner.

Comment: if you really want to, you have to pass every disk witger by setup ewch drive as a single raid (sone old servers have only this kibd of option) or as above told use passthrough